# Salesforce Marketing Cloud Internal Data Views

Tags: marketing-cloud

In Marketing Cloud - I cannot view internal data views (_Sent, _Click, _Open, _Bounce) using a SQL Query Activity.  Is access to data views part of business unit set up or is this a permissions issue?

Comment: what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Here is an example of the message that I get when trying to validate the syntax in SQL Query activity "Errors: [_Job] is not a known data extension or system data view. You can only query existing data extensions or system data views."

Comment: I can add the "ent" to the beginning ("ent._Job") - but then I get only information at the parent level.  No information from my specific business unit.

Comment: Also - I have used the same query in other business units for the same client, so I know it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to ask support to enable Data Views for your account first.

Check out Zuzanna's [article](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/08/22/data-views-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud/) about Data Views. You can start from there..